# Redirection in Authentication Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I´m doing a website, when a normal user log in, it must redirect to a welcome page, if it is an admin user it must redirect to the dashboard. The problem is that only redirect to the welcome page even if it is admin. I am a beginner in laravel and I am not clear about middleware and the routes in **laravel 8** so maybe I am missing something. I will add the most important parts of the code.

**web.php**

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GasController;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('welcome');

Route::resource('gasolina', GasolinaController::class);
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController;

Route::middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.index');
});
```

**AdminMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->admin == True)
        return $next($request);

    return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**LoginController.php**

```
 protected function redirectTo(){
        if (Auth::user()->admin == True){
            return route('admin.index');  // admin path
        } else {
            return route('welcome');  // normal user path
        }
    }
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
            Route::middleware('web', 'auth')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->admin == True) {
        session()->put('url.intended', 'adminURL');
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

add this function into your `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

Comment: Nothing, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your `LoginController`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request)
{
  if (Auth::user()->admin == True){
     return route('admin.index');  // admin path
  } else {
     return route('welcome');  // normal user path
  }
}
```

Comment: It throws an error `TypeError
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\contable\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 110`

Comment: do you have this at the top: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`?

Comment: Sorry that was missing, but now it redirect to a blank page with the url

Comment: is it now redirecting to your routes?

Comment: It redirects to a blank page with the correct route written on it.

Comment: if it is redirecting to a correct route then your question has already been answered. the problem now lies on your route configurations.

Comment: also, can you please try replacing with this: `protected function authenticated()`, then remove the `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top.